# compile daq-1.1.1: can't find -lipq

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, snort

I trying to install daq-1.1.1 modules in ubuntu 12.04 32-bit

I'm configure using syntax:

```
./configure --with-libpcap-includes=/usr/include/libnetfilter_queue --with-libpcap-libraries=/usr/lib
```

and when I trying to compile daq-1.1.1 using a makefile, I encountered the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lipq
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [daq_ipq.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ardi/Downloads/daq-1.1.1/os-daq-modules'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ardi/Downloads/daq-1.1.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this error? thanks

Comment: I have same problem with 12.04 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need this package: iptables-dev.